# WP Custom Permalink Filter

Tags: permalinks

I've got a custom filter which appends the image #ID to the end of the image href, however it returns 2 x url's.

Can anybody see what i'm doing wrong?

```
function modify_attachment_link($markup, $id, $size, $permalink, $icon, $text) {

    $pos = strpos($markup, "href") + 6;
    $remainstring = substr($markup, $pos);
    $pos2 = strpos($remainstring, "'");
    $url = substr($remainstring, 0, $pos2);
    $url .= "#image-".$id;
    return substr_replace($markup, '' . $url . '', $pos, strlen(''));

}
add_filter( 'wp_get_attachment_link', 'modify_attachment_link', 10, 6 );
```

Kind regards. :)

Answer (score 0):

`strlen('')` in `substr_replace` will always evaluate to `0`, which doesn't replace anything. It just inserts the new url at `$pos`.

You could use this:

```
function modify_attachment_link( $markup, $id ) {

    $pos = strpos( $markup, 'href' ) + 6;

    $remainstring = substr( $markup, $pos );
    $pos2 = strpos( $remainstring, "'" );

    $url = substr( $remainstring, 0, $pos2 );
    $url_length = strlen( $url );

    $url .= "#image-$id";
    return substr_replace( $markup, $url, $pos, $url_length );
}
```